# Where does Netbeans remember opened files?

Tags: netbeans

I tried to open a huge SQL file in Netbeans and it hangs now. Restarting does not help because on restart it again tries to open that file. Reinstalling Netbeans does not help. Where does it remember opened files so I could manually delete the appropriate entry for that huge SQL file? Thanks.

Comment: Open home folder,Press ctrl +h Remove/rename .netbeans folder and restart netbeans

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flush the following directory:
`~/.netbeans/{netbeans_version}/var/filehistory/`

Also the cache is located elsewhere:
`~/.cache/netbeans/{netbeans_version}/`

Both of these can cause startup issues, and both are safe to trash *(they will be regenerated on startup if they do not exist or are incomplete)*.

Some advice around the web says to delete the entire `~/.netbeans` folder. Don't do that unless you also want to lose all of your database and service credentials and plugin settings. Only the two above folders need to be trashed to fix your issue.

File structure seems from my experience to be consistent across most all Linux distros, but differs substantially on OSX and Windows. Most answers I've come across address windows, which is purely unhelpful to linux users.

Comment: Thanks :) Jesus, so much time have passed :) I also don't use Netbeans anymore since I saw Storm :) But thanks anyway :) I hope the topic will be usefull to somebody else :)